# Xcode 4.3.3: cannot change autosizing inner markers (springs & struts)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I want to change the spring & struts setting in the storyboard (xcode 4.3.3)

Currently, in the size inspector (auto sizing), two struts are active (outer markers) - the top and the left makers, with zero springs (inner makers) are active.

I would like to activate both the inner markers, but xcode currently does not allow me to click them.

If I create a new `ViewController` and `UIView`, I can change the auto sizing for the new one.
But ideally, I would like to know how to be able to fix this issue, without creating a new storyboard from scratch.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Thanks,